# Authentication error in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run the Big query [sample](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/bigquery.ipynb&scrollTo=gisPvdr4Eaui) provided in the colab samples. But I'm always getting the following error from gcp (Billing is enabled for the project). All the required permissions are clicked and approved in the oauth tab. Some insight for this issue will be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
project_id = 'my-project-id-178304'
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

> WARNING:google.auth._default:No project ID could be determined from
>   the credentials at GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS Consider setting the
>   GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable

Comment: Do you see an error if you execute a query via `pd.io.gpq.read_gbq`? This might be the sort of error you can ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a warning which is (in this case) totally harmless.

Happily, it's already been [fixed upstream](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/221).